# How to get the cell values from column1 and column 3 and put in map as key value pair using excel in java

Tags: java

I have read the sheet 1 column and put in array list having [Sunday, Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday, Friday].

```
Id   Apps           Remarks
------------------------------------------------------------
1    laucher        Sunday will be holiday.
2    ninja          Monday prevails ground.
3    car            kamal act in Wednesday movie.
4    angrybird      Cyclone form may be on Thursday.
5    zedge          Keeps going to temple every Friday.
6    skype          We wen movie to AGS on Saturday.
```

This is the excel file with three columns namely id, apps and remarks. I need to get the cell value from *column1* and the corresponding values from *column3* like

```
1 Sunday will be holiday.
2 Monday prevails ground. 
etc...
```

then store it as key value pair in `Map` using Java. Now compare the value from map contains with the above array list value (ignorecase). How to code this in Java?

Answer (score 1):

Try *Apache POI*, an excellent tool for dealing with excel files.

Answer (score 0):

You can to use [JExcelApi](http://jexcelapi.sourceforge.net/) to read an excel file in Java.
Refer to [this tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/articles/JavaExcel/article.html).